# Is this boolean test pythonic for limiting a list's members to a set of legal values?

Tags: python

I have a list of legal words:

```
legal = ['osama','bin','laden']
```

A function accepts a list that must contain words in the legal list & returns true if every member of the list is a legal word.

```
def is_legal( list ):
   return not any( [tok not in legal for tok in list ] )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to read if you use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) instead of [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
legal = set(['osama','bin','laden'])

def is_legal(seq):
    return all(tok in legal for tok in seq)
```

Comment: Agree this is much more readable. Worth noting that `all()` will iterate over the entire sequence (`seq`) whereas `any()` will stop iterating when it encounters a True (or equivalent). Wether this is important I guess depends on the likely size of the sequence to be tested.

Comment: @Rob: `all()` will stop iterating as soon as it sees a `False`, which is essentially equivalent to the behavior of `any()`.

Comment: Ha, of course it will; My quick test code was flawed, and I clearly wasn't thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the square brackets (since they force creation of a list), and you don't want to shadow builtins, but yes.

```
def is_legal(seq):
    return not any(tok not in legal for tok in seq)
```

Comment: Also this could be `return all((token in legal) for token in list)`

Comment: It's not quite a synonym though, since `list`, `tuple`, and strings are all sequences.

Answer (score 1):

`all((token in LEGAL_TOKENS) for token in mySequence)`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
legal = {'osama','bin','laden'} # or set(['osama','bin','laden']) if not 2.7+
is_legal = legal.issuperset
```